# Missing penultimate value - Yahoo finances

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo, cryptocurrency, mplfinance

Sorry for this thread, because I don't have any technical issue to solve, but I'm curious about some strange behavior in Yahoo finances...

Well - I don't know - maybe it is some problem on my side.

I have trouble with missing penultimate value in readed data from Yahoo (BTC and ETH) and it happens every day.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank You a lot.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf

past = int(365/4)

start = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=past)
end = dt.datetime.now()

btc = web.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', start, end)
eth = web.DataReader('ETH-USD', 'yahoo', start, end)

print("BTC/USD",btc.tail(3))
print("ETH/USD",eth.tail(3))

mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(base_mpf_style='yahoo', edge='#252525', wick='#252525', volume='silver')
s = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=mc, base_mpl_style='ggplot')

fig = mpf.figure()

btcv = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
btcv.set_title('$BTC/USD$')
btcp = btcv.twinx()
btcv.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")
btcv.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position("right")
btcv.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
mpf.plot(btc, type='candle', mav=(7, 14), ax=btcp, volume=btcv, show_nontrading=True, style=s)

ethv = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=btcp)
ethv.set_title('$ETH/USD$')
ethp = ethv.twinx()
ethv.get_yaxis().set_label_position("right")
ethv.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position("right")
# ethv.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
mpf.plot(eth, type='candle', mav=(7, 14), ax=ethp, volume=ethv, show_nontrading=True, style=s)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, top=0.93, bottom=0.05, wspace=0.175, hspace=0.09)
fig.suptitle('Crypto balance', fontsize=20)

wm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
wm.window.state('zoomed')

mpf.show()
```

Here is printed terminal output:
[image]

... and here is graph:
[image]

Comment: With yfinance, I can get 2021-09-07. `btc = yf.download('BTC-USD', start, end)`

Comment: Yes. You're right.
I used yfinance instead of pandas_datareader and it works... 
Thank You. 